# How to send 500 emails from a local pc?

Tags: smtp, email-server

I want to send an email to 500 recipients but I don't want to use any gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc. as they impose several restrictions.

Someone told me to install a SMTP server on your local pc and an emailer that send those messages to that smtp server and then that smtp server will send those emails to those recipients directly to their mailboxes.

He also told me to send emails through your own domain e.g. info@mydomain.com but I haven't any domain. Can I send through fake domain.

Can anyone help me in this.

I am not going to spam them.

Comment: I sense great danger...

Comment: Danger Will Robinson, Danger!

Comment: Everything you have said makes you sound like a spammer.

Comment: Can you give a legitimate reason for asking this question? If have a legit reason, there are ways to do it through normal means and without faking a domain. Otherwise, you sound like a spammer (plus no rep. and you're listed as unknown, so we don't know anything about you) and you get a down vote.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do this by installing the correct mailer software (probably SMTP based), and following the instructions or writing your own script for `sendmail` under any unix like system for which there is a man page and numerous examples online.

Your own domain wouldn't cost a lot. I mean it could cost as little as $3, more likely $10.

The machine you send mail from should have it's IP do reverse name lookup to whatever domain you claim to be sending on behalf of, that likely implies you want to talk to your ISP about getting this all setup for you.

However, that said, unless you carefully follow some basic rules, and the advice of your ISP in this, you're essentially spamming people, even if you think you're not.